# How to create a only mute/unmute button (like youtube) in html

Tags: javascript, html, playback

I was creating a website, I put background music, and my problem is I dont know how to create a button(only one) for mute/unmute the sound. I would like to have a mute button that can mute/unmute depending on the situation(if the music is muted then the button should have the image of a Loudspeaker,for hearing the sound, if you press it then you begin listening the music and the image of the button changes and  vice versa)

what I have now is this:

```
<td width=10% valign="top" align="right">
                            <img  src="images/sonidoON.png" onclick="this.src='images/sonidoOFF.png'" width=30% height=7%>
                        </td>
```

I only need to know how to create that button, not the functions for the background music.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: How are you playing the sound? Just a `bgsound` tag?

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="un-mute" id="un-mute">
<label for="un-mute" class="unmute">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Mute_Icon.svg" alt="Mute_Icon.svg" title="Mute icon">
</label>
<label for="un-mute" class="mute">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Speaker_Icon.svg" alt="Speaker_Icon.svg" title="Unmute/speaker icon">
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
input#un-mute {
  display: none;
}

.unmute img {
  display: none;
}

input#un-mute:checked ~ .unmute img {
  display: initial;
}

input#un-mute:checked ~ .mute img {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var un_mute = document.getElementById('un-mute');

un_mute.onclick = function() {
   alert('toggle player here');
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ffccv/2/

using :checked pseudo-class selector

Answer (score 0):

You can do this To toggle them

```
<script>
function toggleSound(img)
{
   img.src= img.src=="images/sonidoON.png" ? "images/sonidoOFF.png" : "images/sonidoON.png";
}
</script>
```

and `onclick="toggleSound(this);"` or create img from script and use `addEventListener ("click",toggleSound())`

```
<td width=10% valign="top" align="right">
                            <img  src="images/sonidoON.png" onclick="toggleSound(this);" width=30% height=7%>
                        </td>
```

fiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/K9553/